# Getting error on reading comment characters Instagram

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I'm using php to read from INSTAGRAM API, get comment on its media

Eg.

```
sending $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$mediaID.'/comments?client_id='. clientID;
```

I read the results like this:

```
$instagramInfo = connectToInstagram($test);
$results = json_decode($instagramInfo, true);
foreach($results['data'] as $item){
$commentText = $item['text'];
echo $commentText.'<br/>';
}
```

Here's an example of the output:

™آƒأ™آٹأ™آ„ أ™آپأ™آٹأ™آƒ أکآ§أکآ° أ™آ†أ™آٹأکآھأ™آƒ أ™آˆأکآµأکآ®أ™آ‡ أکآ§أ™آ„أ™آ„أ™آ‡ أ™آ„أکآ§ أ™آٹأ™آˆأ™آپأ™آ‚أ™آƒ أ™آˆأ™آ„أکآ§ أ™آٹأکآ³أکآ¹أکآ¯أ™آƒ أکآ­أکآ³أکآ¨أ™آٹ أکآ§أ™آ„أ™آ„أ™آ‡ أ™آˆأ™آ†أکآ¹أ™آ… أکآ§أ™آ„أ™آˆأ™آƒأ™آٹأ™آ„ أکآ§أکآ° أکآ£أ™آ†أکآھ أکآھأ™آپأ™آƒأکآ± أ™آپأ™آٹأ™آ†أ™آٹ أکآ¨أکآ°أکآ§ أکآ§أ™آ„أکآ·أکآ±أ™آٹأ™آ‚أ™آ‡ أکآ±أ™آˆأکآ­ أکآ§أ™آ„أ™آ„أ™آ‡ أ™آ„أکآ§ أ™آٹأکآ³أکآ¹أکآ¯أ™آƒ أ™آ„أکآ§ أکآ¯أ™آ†أ™آٹأکآ§ أ™آˆأ™آ„أکآ§ أکآ¢أکآ®أکآ±

The issue I'm having is the comments are unknown chars. I tried to change the encode to UTF-8 it didn't work

any ideas?

Comment: what does `$test` contain?

Comment: $test=html_entity_decode($url,null,'UTF-8');

Comment: what happens when you use `print_r()` on `$results`? can you show me the outcome?

Comment: I couldn't put all it's too long

Comment: no problem, i'm just a bit confused, because if I look at your code it should work without any problem....

Comment: I tried to do this <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
</head>

Comment: I'm not sure If the problem is encoding or not

Comment: `$instagramInfo = connectToInstagram($test);`
`$results = json_decode($instagramInfo, true);`
`foreach($results['data'] as $item){`
`$commentText = htmlspecialchars($item['text']);`
`echo $commentText.'<br/>';`
`}`

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Comment: still the same problem exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this should escape all special characters, and probably wouldn't cause any problems anymore

```
$instagramInfo = connectToInstagram($test);
$results = json_decode($instagramInfo, true);
foreach($results['data'] as $item){
    $commentText = htmlspecialchars($item['text']);
    echo $commentText.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: still the same problem exists

Comment: Then I have no clue what the problem could be, sorry